# JSON Web Token (JWT) with Spring based SockJS / STOMP Web Socket

Tags: spring, spring-security, websocket, jwt, sockjs

## Background

I am in the process of setting up a RESTful web application using Spring Boot (1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT) that includes a STOMP/SockJS WebSocket, which I intend to consume from an iOS app as well as web browsers. I want to use [JSON Web Tokens](http://jwt.io) (JWT) to secure the REST requests and the WebSocket interface but I’m having difficulty with the latter.

The app is secured with Spring Security:-

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public WebSecurityConfiguration() {
        super(true);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("steve").password("steve").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .exceptionHandling().and()
            .anonymous().and()
            .servletApi().and()
            .headers().cacheControl().and().and()

            // Relax CSRF on the WebSocket due to needing direct access from apps
            .csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/ws/**").and()

            .authorizeRequests()

            //allow anonymous resource requests
            .antMatchers("/", "/index.html").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()

            //allow anonymous POSTs to JWT
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/rest/jwt/token").permitAll()

            // Allow anonymous access to websocket 
            .antMatchers("/ws/**").permitAll()

            //all other request need to be authenticated
            .anyRequest().hasRole("USER").and()

            // Custom authentication on requests to /rest/jwt/token
            .addFilterBefore(new JWTLoginFilter("/rest/jwt/token", authenticationManagerBean()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)

            // Custom JWT based authentication
            .addFilterBefore(new JWTTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

}
```

The WebSocket configuration is standard:-

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfiguration extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").withSockJS();
    }

}
```

I also have a subclass of `AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer` to secure the WebSocket:-

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketSecurityConfiguration extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
        messages.anyMessage().hasRole("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
        // We need to access this directly from apps, so can't do cross-site checks
        return true;
    }

}
```

There is also a couple of `@RestController` annotated classes to handle various bits of functionality and these are secured successfully via the `JWTTokenFilter` registered in my `WebSecurityConfiguration` class.

## Problem

However I can't seem to get the WebSocket to be secured with JWT. I am using [SockJS 1.1.0](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client/releases/tag/v1.0.0) and [STOMP 1.7.1](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jmesnil/stomp-websocket/master/lib/stomp.js) in the browser and can't figure out how to pass the token. It [would appear that](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client/issues/196) SockJS does not allow parameters to be sent with the initial `/info` and/or handshake requests.

The [Spring Security for WebSockets documentation states](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.x/reference/html/websocket.html) that the `AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer` ensures that:

> Any inbound CONNECT message requires a valid CSRF token to enforce Same Origin Policy

Which seems to imply that the initial handshake should be unsecured and authentication invoked at the point of receiving a STOMP CONNECT message. Unfortunately I can't seem to find any information with regards to implementing this. Additionally this approach would require additional logic to disconnect a rogue client that opens a WebSocket connection and never sends a STOMP CONNECT.

Being (very) new to Spring I'm also not sure if or how Spring Sessions fits into this. While the documentation is very detailed there doesn't appear to a nice and simple (aka idiots) guide to how the various components fit together / interact with each other.

## Question

How do I go about securing the SockJS WebSocket by providing a JSON Web Token, preferably at the point of handshake (is it even possible)?

Comment: Hi...You have change the default login url from `/login` to `/rest/jwt/token`. In the same way how to change the default spring-security logout url from `/logout` to `/rest/logout`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems like support for a query string was added to the SockJS client, see https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client/issues/72.

Comment: Embarrassed I missed this. It appears to work though I'm taking it with a pinch of salt as I'm not sure how it'll be affected by HTTP GET length limits.

Comment: Still doesn't work for SockJS websocket fallbacks. See https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14690.

Answer (score 73):

### Current Situation

**UPDATE 2016-12-13** : the issue referenced below is now marked fixed, so the hack below is no longer necessary which Spring 4.3.5 or above. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/src/docs/asciidoc/web/websocket.adoc#token-authentication.

### Previous Situation

Currently (Sep 2016), this is not supported by Spring except via query parameter as answered by @rossen-stoyanchev, who wrote a lot (all?) of the Spring WebSocket support. I don't like the query parameter approach because of potential HTTP referrer leakage and storage of the token in server logs. In addition, if the security ramifications don't bother you, note that I have found this approach works for true WebSocket connections, *but* if you are using SockJS with fallbacks to other mechanisms, the `determineUser` method is never called for the fallback. See [Spring 4.x token-based WebSocket SockJS fallback authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39422053/spring-4-x-token-based-websocket-sockjs-fallback-authentication).

I've created a Spring issue to improve support for token-based WebSocket authentication: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14690

### Hacking It

In the meantime, I've found a hack that works well in testing. Bypass the built-in Spring connection-level Spring auth machinery. Instead, set the authentication token at the message-level by sending it in the Stomp headers on the client side (this nicely mirrors what you are already doing with regular HTTP XHR calls) e.g.:

```
stompClient.connect({'X-Authorization': 'token'}, ...);
stompClient.subscribe(..., {'X-Authorization': 'token'});
stompClient.send("/wherever", {'X-Authorization': 'token'}, ...);
```

On the server-side, obtain the token from the Stomp message using a `ChannelInterceptor`

```
@Override
public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
  registration.setInterceptors(new ChannelInterceptorAdapter() {
     Message<*> preSend(Message<*> message,  MessageChannel channel) {
      StompHeaderAccessor accessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(message);
      List tokenList = accessor.getNativeHeader("X-Authorization");
      String token = null;
      if(tokenList == null || tokenList.size < 1) {
        return message;
      } else {
        token = tokenList.get(0);
        if(token == null) {
          return message;
        }
      }

      // validate and convert to a Principal based on your own requirements e.g.
      // authenticationManager.authenticate(JwtAuthentication(token))
      Principal yourAuth = [...];

      accessor.setUser(yourAuth);

      // not documented anywhere but necessary otherwise NPE in StompSubProtocolHandler!
      accessor.setLeaveMutable(true);
      return MessageBuilder.createMessage(message.payload, accessor.messageHeaders)
    }
  })
```

This is simple and gets us 85% of the way there, however, this approach does not support sending messages to specific users. This is because Spring's machinery to associate users to sessions is not affected by the result of the `ChannelInterceptor`. Spring WebSocket assumes authentication is done at the transport layer, not the message layer, and thus ignores the message-level authentication.

The hack to make this work anyway, is to create our instances of `DefaultSimpUserRegistry` and `DefaultUserDestinationResolver`, expose those to the environment, and then use the interceptor to update those as if Spring itself was doing it. In other words, something like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@Order(HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 50)
class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer() {
  private DefaultSimpUserRegistry userRegistry = new DefaultSimpUserRegistry();
  private DefaultUserDestinationResolver resolver = new DefaultUserDestinationResolver(userRegistry);

  @Bean
  @Primary
  public SimpUserRegistry userRegistry() {
    return userRegistry;
  }

  @Bean
  @Primary
  public UserDestinationResolver userDestinationResolver() {
    return resolver;
  }


  @Override
  public configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/queue", "/topic");
  }

  @Override
  public registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry
      .addEndpoint("/stomp")
      .withSockJS()
      .setWebSocketEnabled(false)
      .setSessionCookieNeeded(false);
  }

  @Override public configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
    registration.setInterceptors(new ChannelInterceptorAdapter() {
       Message<*> preSend(Message<*> message,  MessageChannel channel) {
        StompHeaderAccessor accessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(message);

        List tokenList = accessor.getNativeHeader("X-Authorization");
        accessor.removeNativeHeader("X-Authorization");

        String token = null;
        if(tokenList != null && tokenList.size > 0) {
          token = tokenList.get(0);
        }

        // validate and convert to a Principal based on your own requirements e.g.
        // authenticationManager.authenticate(JwtAuthentication(token))
        Principal yourAuth = token == null ? null : [...];

        if (accessor.messageType == SimpMessageType.CONNECT) {
          userRegistry.onApplicationEvent(SessionConnectedEvent(this, message, yourAuth));
        } else if (accessor.messageType == SimpMessageType.SUBSCRIBE) {
          userRegistry.onApplicationEvent(SessionSubscribeEvent(this, message, yourAuth));
        } else if (accessor.messageType == SimpMessageType.UNSUBSCRIBE) {
          userRegistry.onApplicationEvent(SessionUnsubscribeEvent(this, message, yourAuth));
        } else if (accessor.messageType == SimpMessageType.DISCONNECT) {
          userRegistry.onApplicationEvent(SessionDisconnectEvent(this, message, accessor.sessionId, CloseStatus.NORMAL));
        }

        accessor.setUser(yourAuth);

        // not documented anywhere but necessary otherwise NPE in StompSubProtocolHandler!
        accessor.setLeaveMutable(true);
        return MessageBuilder.createMessage(message.payload, accessor.messageHeaders);
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Now Spring is fully aware of the the authentication i.e. it injects the `Principal` into any controller methods that require it, exposes it to the context for Spring Security 4.x, and associates the user to the WebSocket session for sending messages to specific users/sessions.

### Spring Security Messaging

Lastly, if you use Spring Security 4.x Messaging support, make sure to set the `@Order` of your `AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer` to a higher value than Spring Security's `AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer` (`Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 50` would work, as shown above). That way, your interceptor sets the `Principal` before Spring Security executes its check and sets the security context.

### Creating a Principal (Update June 2018)

Lots of people seem to be confused by this line in the code above:

```
  // validate and convert to a Principal based on your own requirements e.g.
  // authenticationManager.authenticate(JwtAuthentication(token))
  Principal yourAuth = [...];
```

This is pretty much out of scope for the question as it is not Stomp-specific, but I'll expand on it a little bit anyway, because its related to using auth tokens with Spring. When using token-based authentication, the `Principal` you need will generally be a custom `JwtAuthentication` class that extends Spring Security's `AbstractAuthenticationToken` class. `AbstractAuthenticationToken` implements the `Authentication` interface which extends the `Principal` interface, and contains most of the machinery to integrate your token with Spring Security.

So, in Kotlin code (sorry I don't have the time or inclination to translate this back to Java), your `JwtAuthentication` might look something like this, which is a simple wrapper around `AbstractAuthenticationToken`:

```
import my.model.UserEntity
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationToken
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority

class JwtAuthentication(
  val token: String,
  // UserEntity is your application's model for your user
  val user: UserEntity? = null,
  authorities: Collection<GrantedAuthority>? = null) : AbstractAuthenticationToken(authorities) {

  override fun getCredentials(): Any? = token

  override fun getName(): String? = user?.id

  override fun getPrincipal(): Any? = user
}
```

Now you need an `AuthenticationManager` that knows how to deal with it. This might look something like the following, again in Kotlin:

```
@Component
class CustomTokenAuthenticationManager @Inject constructor(
  val tokenHandler: TokenHandler,
  val authService: AuthService) : AuthenticationManager {

  val log = logger()

  override fun authenticate(authentication: Authentication?): Authentication? {
    return when(authentication) {
      // for login via username/password e.g. crash shell
      is UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken -> {
        findUser(authentication).let {
          //checkUser(it)
          authentication.withGrantedAuthorities(it).also { setAuthenticated(true) }
        }
      }
      // for token-based auth
      is JwtAuthentication -> {
        findUser(authentication).let {
          val tokenTypeClaim = tokenHandler.parseToken(authentication.token)[CLAIM_TOKEN_TYPE]
          when(tokenTypeClaim) {
            TOKEN_TYPE_ACCESS -> {
              //checkUser(it)
              authentication.withGrantedAuthorities(it).also { setAuthenticated(true) }
            }
            TOKEN_TYPE_REFRESH -> {
              //checkUser(it)
              JwtAuthentication(authentication.token, it, listOf(SimpleGrantedAuthority(Authorities.REFRESH_TOKEN)))
            }
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected token type claim $tokenTypeClaim.")
          }
        }
      }
      else -> null
    }
  }

  private fun findUser(authentication: JwtAuthentication): UserEntity =
    authService.login(authentication.token) ?:
      throw BadCredentialsException("No user associated with token or token revoked.")

  private fun findUser(authentication: UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken): UserEntity =
    authService.login(authentication.principal.toString(), authentication.credentials.toString()) ?:
      throw BadCredentialsException("Invalid login.")

  @Suppress("unused", "UNUSED_PARAMETER")
  private fun checkUser(user: UserEntity) {
    // TODO add these and lock account on x attempts
    //if(!user.enabled) throw DisabledException("User is disabled.")
    //if(user.accountLocked) throw LockedException("User account is locked.")
  }

  fun JwtAuthentication.withGrantedAuthorities(user: UserEntity): JwtAuthentication {
    return JwtAuthentication(token, user, authoritiesOf(user))
  }

  fun UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.withGrantedAuthorities(user: UserEntity): UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken {
    return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, credentials, authoritiesOf(user))
  }

  private fun authoritiesOf(user: UserEntity) = user.authorities.map(::SimpleGrantedAuthority)
}
```

The injected `TokenHandler` abstracts away the JWT token parsing, but should use a common JWT token library like [jjwt](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt). The injected `AuthService` is your abstraction that actually creates your `UserEntity` based on the claims in the token, and may talk to your user database or other backend system(s).

Now, coming back to the line we started with, it might look something like this, where `authenticationManager` is an `AuthenticationManager` injected into our adapter by Spring, and is an instance of `CustomTokenAuthenticationManager` we defined above:

```
Principal yourAuth = token == null ? null : authenticationManager.authenticate(new JwtAuthentication(token));
```

This principal is then attached to the message as described above. HTH!

Comment: The link https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/src/asciidoc/web-websocket.adoc#token-based-authentication is not working

Comment: Awesome, I also found the document too: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-authentication-token-based

Comment: @Raman your example is not working. I get a 'Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Principal' when trying to set the Principal to be the token. Is that right?

Comment: @PedroChiiip You have to convert to a `Principal` based on your own setup. For example, you might inject your `AuthenticationManager` and do something like: `authenticationManager.authenticate(JwtAuthentication(token))` in order to obtain an `Authentication` (which implements `Principal`).

Comment: Has anybody done this using keycloak bearer token? I can't find a way to convert the bearer token in the stomp header to a Principal.

Comment: @adrianmoya Is the keycloak bearer token opaque? In that case you probably need to make an API call to KeyCloak to get the user details with which you can create the `Principal`. If you can obtain the user details from the token itself, then you can create a `Principal` based on those directly.

Comment: @Raman It's opaque. I was looking for something to actually verify that token, bacause I may be able to get the details from the token, but I must validate that the token is indeed valid. Something in the lines of `Principal principal = authenticationManager.authenticate(new KeycloakToken("token")); ` but I can't find something similar in the API.

Comment: @adrianmoya According to https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.0/authorization_services/topics/service/protection/token-introspection.html, the token is not opaque -- its a standard JWT token. That means you can use any JWT library e.g. https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt to validate the token and obtain the claims from it. Now all you need to do is create your own `KeycloakAuthenticationManager` that returns a `KeycloakAuthentication` which extends `AbstractAuthenticationToken`.

Comment: @adrianmoya See the section I added to the answer `Creating a Principal (Update June 2018)`. I hope that is helpful to you and others.

Comment: @Raman thank you for that additional section! It has helped me understand a bit more, I'll try to code the thing today starting from there.

Comment: @Raman here's the final result applying your comments, it worked like a charm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50573461/spring-websockets-authentication-with-spring-security-and-keycloak/50867554

Comment: @Raman Could you explain what exactly isnt needed in the newer spring security versions? Spring docs (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#websocket-stomp-authentication-token-based) give similar code to yours in the current version. Also why do we need to create our own userRegistry (and destinationresolver which isnt used at all) if according to docs (https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-4.2.html) there should already be userRegistery bean exposed by spring (couldnt get it to work tho)?

Comment: I would also add that using SecurityContextHolder.getContext() returns null Authentication object, despite authentication is actually done. Just let spring inject Authentication object to your controller handler method along with the message you receive.

Comment: is there any info on how to do this with https://stomp-js.github.io/guide/stompjs/upgrading-stompjs.html? it looks like you should be able to pass `connectHeaders` when creating the client, however those headers don't seem to be propagated when using sockjs.

Answer (score 14):

With the latest SockJS 1.0.3 you can pass query parameters as a part of connection URL. Thus you can send some JWT token to authorize a session.

```
  var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost/ws?token=AAA');
  var stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
  stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
      stompClient.subscribe('/topic/echo', function(data) {
        // topic handler
      });
    }
  }, function(err) {
    // connection error
  });
```

Now all the requests related to websocket will have parameter "?token=AAA"

http://localhost/ws/info?token=AAA&t=1446482506843

http://localhost/ws/515/z45wjz24/websocket?token=AAA

Then with Spring you can setup some filter which will identify a session using provided token.

Comment: Interesting. I'm no longer working on this project but will keep that in mind. Thanks :)

Comment: If getting strange error 'failed: Unexpected response code: 200', just add '/websocket' to URL. So it will look like `http://localhost/ws/websocket?token=AAA`

Comment: Isn't it a bad practice to send token via url? For security reasons ofc.

Comment: This is bad practice, and a security concern.

Answer (score 9):

As of now, it is possible either to add auth token as a request parameter and handle it on a handshake, or add it as a header on a connection to stomp endpoint, and handle it on the `CONNECT` command in the interceptor.

Best thing would be to use header, but the problem is that you can't access native header on the handshake step, so you wouldn't be able to handle the auth there then.

Let me give some example code:

Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws-test")
                .setHandshakeHandler(new SecDefaultHandshakeHandler())
                .addInterceptors(new HttpHandshakeInterceptor())
                .withSockJS()
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
        registration.interceptors(new JwtChannelInterceptor())
    }
}
```

Handshake interceptor:

```
public class HttpHandshakeInterceptor implements HandshakeInterceptor {
    public boolean beforeHandshake(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response, WebSocketHandler handler, Map<String, Object> attributes) {
        attributes.put("token", request.getServletRequest().getParameter("auth_token")
        return true
    }
}
```

Handshake handler:

```
public class SecDefaultHandshakeHandler extends DefaultHandshakeHandler {
    @Override
    public Principal determineUser(ServerHttpRequest request, WebSocketHandler handler, Map<String, Object> attributes) {
        Object token = attributes.get("token")
        //handle authorization here
    }
}
```

Channel Interceptor:

```
public class JwtChannelInterceptor implements ChannelInterceptor {
    @Override
    public void postSend(Message message, MessageChannel channel, Boolean sent) {
        MessageHeaderAccessor accessor = MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class)

        if (StompCommand.DISCONNECT == accessor.getCommand()) {
            //retrieve Principal here via accessor.getUser()
            //or get auth header from the accessor and handle authorization
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for possible compile mistakes, I was converting manually from Kotlin code =)

As you mentioned that you have both web and mobile clients for your WebSockets, please mind that there are some difficulties maintaining same codebase for all clients. Please see my thread: [Spring Websocket ChannelInterceptor not firing CONNECT event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59470938/spring-websocket-channelinterceptor-not-firing-connect-event)

Answer (score 2):

I spend a lot of time to find simple solution. For me solution of Raman didn't work.
All you need is define custom **bearerTokenResolver** method and put access token into cookies or parameter.

```
    @Configuration
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.cors()
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/user/info", "/api/foos/**")
                    .hasAuthority("SCOPE_read")
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/foos")
                    .hasAuthority("SCOPE_write")
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt().and().bearerTokenResolver(this::tokenExtractor);
}
...
}

public String tokenExtractor(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String header = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
    if (header != null)
        return header.replace("Bearer ", "");
    Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "access_token");
    if (cookie != null)
        return cookie.getValue();
    return null;
}
```

Comment: This is actually a great solution! 
I'd add one extra condition to tokenExtractor: 

```String token = request.getParameter("token");
        if (!token.isEmpty()) {
            return token;
        }```

This is for a situation when you want to parse a token sent by query param

Answer (score 0):

For those using ouath2 resource server

```
http.oauth2ResourceServer(
                    oauth2 -> oauth2
                            .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults())
            );
```

And wanting to authenticate token using `CONNECT` headers, use `JwtAuthenticationProvider`:

```
@Configuration
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 99)
public class WebSocketAuthConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    private final JwtAuthenticationProvider jwtAuthenticationProvider;

    public WebSocketAuthConfig(JwtDecoder jwtDecoder, JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter) {
        this.jwtAuthenticationProvider = new JwtAuthenticationProvider(jwtDecoder);
        this.jwtAuthenticationProvider.setJwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
        registration.interceptors(new ChannelInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public Message<?> preSend(@NonNull Message<?> message, @NonNull MessageChannel channel) {
                StompHeaderAccessor accessor = MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);
                assert accessor != null;
                if (StompCommand.CONNECT.equals(accessor.getCommand())) {
                    String token = accessor.getFirstNativeHeader("token");
                    if(token != null)
                    {
                        accessor.setUser(jwtAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(new BearerTokenAuthenticationToken(token)));
                    }
                }
                return message;
            }
        });
    }
}
```