# Providing auth header with SockJS

Tags: spring, rest, model-view-controller, websocket, sockjs

I have a Spring MVC server that provides a bunch of REST endpoints as well as a websocket endpoint.  Everything except the login endpoint requires authentication.  I'm using JWT to authenticate requests coming from the client.

When the user logs in I'm returning an X-AUTH-TOKEN header, containing the JWT token.  This token is then passed in the same header on every request to the server.  This all works fine for the REST endpoints, but I can't figure out how to do this on the websocket.

I'm using SockJS, and when I open the connection:

```
var socket = new SockJS('/socket/updates', null, {});
```

This causes a GET request to /socket/updates/info?t=xxx which returns a 403 (as everything requires auth by default).

Ideally I'd simply send my X-AUTH-TOKEN header on any XHR requests SockJS makes, but I can't see any way of adding headers looking at the API.

Worst case I can change SockJS to do this, but I'm wondering whether this functionality has been deliberately left out? I know SockJS doesn't support cookies for security reasons but that's not what I'm trying to do.

Also, for the sake of a test I did allow the info endpoint to have anonymous access but then it 403's on a bunch of other endpoints - it feels more elegant to simply pass in auth details on these requests than poke holes in my server security.

Any help appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 6):

You cannot set the header from SockJS. Not because SockJS does not have this functionality, but because browser makers don't expose this API to Javascript. See:

https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client/issues/196

For a workaround, see [JSON Web Token (JWT) with Spring based SockJS / STOMP Web Socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30887788/json-web-token-jwt-with-spring-based-sockjs-stomp-web-socket).

Comment: any change so far? Does it work now in 2019? 
I've tried new ```SockJS(url, {headers : {Authorization : 'Bearer <TOKEN>' }}``` and when I debug in the dev console tab network, I see that the request doesn't have a Authorization header (headers are not taken into account)

Comment: May be now any changes in 2022?))

Answer (score 0):

client side:

```
stompClient.connect({headername:header}, function () {
                setConnected(true);
                stompClient.subscribe(request.topic, function (message) {
                    output(message.body);
                });
            });
```

server side :

```
StompHeaderAccessor accessor
                        = MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);

 String headervalue= accessor.getNativeHeader("your header name").get(0);
```

Comment: This sets STOMP header, not an HTTP header, so as it may be a part of workaround it does not solve initial issue which is unability to add custom HTTP header to the SockJS handshake request.

Comment: @egelev, kindly remove the link from your comment or update it. It is no redirecting to the said resource