# How to fix cors ''Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in Spring Boot WebSocket App?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, cors, spring-websocket

all. I'm new to Spring Boot and Websocket. This is my first integrated React and Spring Boot project and I'm currently building a chat app with a backend using WebSocket.

As mentioned, my front end is built in React (localhost:3000), but when trying to call the backend/chat app, I get an error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:9090/ws/info?t=1652731448126' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

I've tried looking up a few possible solutions, such as using `@CrossOrigin(origins = "https://localhost:3000")` and `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")` but that didn't change anything. I also tried `(@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")` with no luck. Both efforts resulted in the same error message.

Chat Controller:

```
package com.project2.chatapi.controller;

import com.project2.chatapi.models.Message;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.MessageMapping;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Payload;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.SendTo;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "https://localhost:3000")
@Controller
public class ChatController {

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;

    /**
     * Handles messages coming into the public chatroom
     * @param message
     * @return message
     */
    @MessageMapping("/message")  // /app/message
    @SendTo("/chatroom/public")
    public Message receivePublicMessage(@Payload Message message) {
        return message;
    }

    /**
     * Handles messages being sent to a private chat
     * Receives the message from a user and sends to another user
     * @param message
     * @return message
     */
    @MessageMapping("/private-message")
    public Message receivePrivateMessage(@Payload Message message) {
        simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(message.getReceiverName(), "/private", message); // listens to /user/name/private
        return message;
    }
}
```

WebsocketConfig class:

```
package com.project2.chatapi.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebsocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    /**
     * Adding endpoint to the chat
     * @param registry
     */
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws")
                .setAllowedOriginPatterns("http://localhost:3000")
                .withSockJS();
    }

    /**
     * Configuring application destination prefixes
     * Adding topic prefixes - chatroom, and user
     * @param registry
     */
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/chat");
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/chatroom","/user");
        registry.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfig() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {

            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
                        .allowedHeaders("*")
                        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

React Method that calls the backend:

```
    const connect = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setUserData({...userData, "username": username});
        let Sock = new SockJS('http://localhost:9090/ws');
        stompClient = over(Sock);
        stompClient.connect({},onConnected, onError);
    }
```

I've also tried implementing different possible solutions regarding setAllowedOrigins. I've tried a handful of combinations including ("http://localhost:3000") and ("*")-- but again, it doesn't seem to change my error message.

I've been stuck on this for days now. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

UPDATE:
These are the additional things I've tried since posting this question originally. Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same errors with these attempts.

1. I tried adding a filter

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleCORSFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        Filter.super.init(filterConfig);
        logger.info("Initializing Middleware");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest requestToUse = (HttpServletRequest)servletRequest;
        HttpServletResponse responseToUse = (HttpServletResponse)servletResponse;

        responseToUse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",requestToUse.getHeader("Origin"));
        filterChain.doFilter(requestToUse,responseToUse);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        Filter.super.destroy();
    }
}
```

2. I tried adding cors mapping in my config file
3. Also tried adding a CorsConfirgurationSource to my config file

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebsocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    // can possibly delete
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                .allowCredentials(false)
                .maxAge(3600)
                .allowedHeaders("Accept", "Content-Type", "Origin",
                        "Authorization", "X-Auth-Token")
                .exposedHeaders("X-Auth-Token", "Authorization")
                .allowedMethods("POST", "GET", "DELETE", "PUT", "OPTIONS");
    }

    /**
     * Adding endpoint to the chat
     * @param registry
     */
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws/*")
                .setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                .withSockJS();
    }

    /**
     * Configuring application destination prefixes
     * Adding topic prefixes - chatroom, and user
     * @param registry
     */
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/chat");
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/chatroom","/user");
        registry.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");
    }
//
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfig() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {

            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/ws/**")
                        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
                        .allowedHeaders("*")
                        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {

        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization"));
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:3000");
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("*");
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        configuration.applyPermitDefaultValues();
        return source;
    }
}
```

4. adding the cors mapping and WebMvcConfigurer to my main app

```
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/*").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
            }
        };
    }
```

[image]
I've checked the network logs in my google chrome browser and it is still showing `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` despite all the configuration.

Comment: maybe change `.allowCredentials(false)` to `.allowCredentials(true)` since you already have the `Authorization` header set?

Comment: or maybe this could help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32393519/providing-auth-header-with-sockjs

Comment: I'm currently not using JWT or a web token for this chat. So not fully applicable either.

Comment: did you find a solution ? I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 3):

this solved my problem

```
 @Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry
    .setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000") // not setAllowedOriginPatterns  
    .withSockJS();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved it like this. As I am testing it locally for that reason it is the localhost, for production remove the localhost.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;

@Configurable
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    private String url = "http://localhost:4200";

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/chat-websocket")
        .setAllowedOrigins(url)
        .withSockJS();

    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/chat/");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Bean
    WebMvcConfigurer corsConfig() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {

            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/ws/**")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowedOrigins(url);
            }
        };
    }

}
```