# Spring STOMP Token Based Security

Tags: java, spring, stomp

I want to implement token based authentication for web socket connection.

My backend system is **server** and a machine is **client**, how to implement authentication during sending and receiving message between machine and server, no user authentication here.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class MyConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
    registration.setInterceptors(new ChannelInterceptorAdapter() {

        @Override
        public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {

            StompHeaderAccessor accessor =
                MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);

            if (StompCommand.CONNECT.equals(accessor.getCommand())) {
                String authToken = accessor.getFirstNativeHeader("X-Auth-Token");
                log.debug("webSocket token is {}", authToken);
                Principal user = ... ; // access authentication header(s)
                accessor.setUser(user);
            }

            return message;
        }
    });
  }
}
```

However, I'm totally lost how I would do at "Principal user = ... ;". How would I get Principle with the token? As here no user exist, only communication between a machine and a backend server

Comment: Are you asking how to authenticate a client with a server without user interaction and create a token to use on the client? Or do you already have a token and you're asking how to get a principal from the token?

Comment: how to authenticate a client with a server without user interaction and create a token to use on the client?

Comment: How does your application get on to a client device? Does a user download and install it? Can you provide more info about the nature of the client app?

Comment: Client subscribe the message in a topic and sever fetch the message from the subscription url, as client will connect with server...

Answer (score 0):

Guess you can try to get principal from spring security context

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

Comment: But without login, may I get the Principle? as here only communicate server and client, no user involved here..

Comment: There is token based auth. http://websystique.com/spring-security/secure-spring-rest-api-using-oauth2/ so instead of login/password you include a token in http header. Google for oauth http-basic examples. Not sure how to add this to web sockets properly.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might need a solution similar to something that would be used by someone building an IoT solution. A good starting point would be to have a look at OpenID Connect.

There's a good article here discussing the related challenges and solutions:
https://www.gluu.org/blog/oauth2-for-iot/

OpenId Connect's site:
http://openid.net/connect/

Answer (score 0):

I know this issue has been around for a long time, and there are already plenty of answers available on Stack Overflow, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39456274) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50867554). These answers indeed fix this issue but all are trying to have their own implementations of the `Principle` interface which is not needed as Spring Security has already implemented all we need.

**Answer your question:** The principle needs to be created from the token provided in the request. You can easily convert string token to a `Principle` by using `new BearerTokenAuthenticationToken("token-string-without-bearer")`, then after that, you should authenticate the token by using `authenticationManager.authenticate(bearerTokenAuthenticationToken)`. Therefore, the code is like this:

```java
// access authentication header(s)
Principal user = authenticationManager.authenticate(new BearerTokenAuthenticationToken(authToken));
```

The full implementation of the `configureClientInboundChannel` method should be (sorry I only have Kotlin code, but you should be able to get the idea):

```
    override fun configureClientInboundChannel(registration: ChannelRegistration) {
        registration.interceptors(object : ChannelInterceptor {
            override fun preSend(message: Message<*>, channel: MessageChannel): Message<*>? {
                val accessor = MessageHeaderAccessor
                        .getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor::class.java)

                if (accessor != null && accessor.command == StompCommand.CONNECT) {
                    // assume the value of Authorization header has Bearer at the beginning
                    val authorization = accessor.getFirstNativeHeader("Authorization")
                            ?.split(" ", limit = 2)
                            ?: return message

                    // check token type is Bearer
                    if (authorization.getOrNull(0) == "Bearer") {

                        val token = authorization.getOrNull(1)?.takeIf { it.isNotBlank() }
                        // if token exists, authenticate and (if succeeded) then assign user to the session
                        if (token != null) {
                            val user = try {
                                authenticationManager.authenticate(BearerTokenAuthenticationToken(token))
                            } catch (ex: AuthenticationException) {
                                // if throw an exception, do not touch the user header
                                null
                            }
                            if (user != null) {
                                accessor.user = user
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return message
            }
        })
    }
```

Note that `BearerTokenAuthenticationToken` comes from `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`, so you need this dependency in order to use it.

`authenticationManager` comes from the implementation of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, exposing as a Bean by overriding `authenticationManagerBean` method and mark it as `@Bean`, and then injecting the Bean into your `AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer` implementation, which in this case, is `MyConfig`.

Also, don't forget to mark `MyConfig` class with `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 99)`
 so that it sets up the user header before Spring Security takeover.