# Spring Websockets Authentication with Spring Security and Keycloak

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, websocket, keycloak

I'm using Spring Boot (v1.5.10.RELEASE) to create a backend for an application written in Angular. The back is secured using spring security + keycloak. Now I'm adding a websocket, using STOMP over SockJS, and wanted to secure it. I'm trying to follow the docs at [Websocket Token Authentication](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#websocket-stomp-authentication-token-based), and it shows the following piece of code:

```
if (StompCommand.CONNECT.equals(accessor.getCommand())) {
  Authentication user = ... ; // access authentication header(s)
  accessor.setUser(user);
}
```

I'm able to retrieve the bearer token from the client using:

```
String token = accessor.getNativeHeader("Authorization").get(0);
```

My question is, how can I convert that to an Authentication object? Or how to proceed from here? Because I always get 403. This is my websocket security config:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketSecurityConfig extends 
     AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry 
    messages) {
messages.simpDestMatchers("/app/**").authenticated().simpSubscribeDestMatchers("/topic/**").authenticated()
    .anyMessage().denyAll();
}

  @Override
  protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

And this is the Web security configuration:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider())
        .addFilterBefore(keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .sessionManagement()
          .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
          .sessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy())
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
          .requestMatchers(new NegatedRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/management/**")))
            .hasRole("USER");
  }

  @Override
  protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
    return new NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy();
  }

  @Bean
  public KeycloakConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
    return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
  }

}
```

Any help or ideas are welcome.

Comment: The KC Spring Security Adapter is based in a web session which is managed by a cookie, linked to an access token. If you're able to use the session over the socket (it seems you can: https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/boot-websocket.html), then you should be able to get the adapter into the game.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? I checked on that doc and tried to activate spring-session but I think it's not going to work because the app is stateless, I'm adding part of the configuration for the KC security adapter.

Comment: Can you add client code to understand how u have sent Auth token from client side?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I was able to enable token based authentication, following the recomendations by [Raman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/430128/raman) on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30887788/json-web-token-jwt-with-spring-based-sockjs-stomp-web-socket/39456274?noredirect=1#comment88308957_39456274). Here's the final code to make it work:

1) First, create a class that represent the JWS auth token:

```
public class JWSAuthenticationToken extends AbstractAuthenticationToken implements Authentication {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private String token;
  private User principal;

  public JWSAuthenticationToken(String token) {
    this(token, null, null);
  }

  public JWSAuthenticationToken(String token, User principal, Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    super(authorities);
    this.token = token;
    this.principal = principal;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getCredentials() {
    return token;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getPrincipal() {
    return principal;
  }

}
```

2) Then, create an authenticator that handles the JWSToken, validating against keycloak. User is my own app class that represents a user:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@Qualifier("websocket")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class KeycloakWebSocketAuthManager implements AuthenticationManager {

  private final KeycloakTokenVerifier tokenVerifier;

  @Override
  public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    JWSAuthenticationToken token = (JWSAuthenticationToken) authentication;
    String tokenString = (String) token.getCredentials();
    try {
      AccessToken accessToken = tokenVerifier.verifyToken(tokenString);
      List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = accessToken.getRealmAccess().getRoles().stream()
          .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
      User user = new User(accessToken.getName(), accessToken.getEmail(), accessToken.getPreferredUsername(),
          accessToken.getRealmAccess().getRoles());
      token = new JWSAuthenticationToken(tokenString, user, authorities);
      token.setAuthenticated(true);
    } catch (VerificationException e) {
      log.debug("Exception authenticating the token {}:", tokenString, e);
      throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid token");
    }
    return token;
  }

}
```

3) The class that actually validates the token against keycloak by calling the certs endpoint to validate the token signature, based on [this gists](https://gist.github.com/thomasdarimont/52152ed68486c65b50a04fcf7bd9bbde). It returns a keycloak AccessToken:

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class KeycloakTokenVerifier {

  private final KeycloakProperties config;

  /**
   * Verifies a token against a keycloak instance
   * @param tokenString the string representation of the jws token
   * @return a validated keycloak AccessToken
   * @throws VerificationException when the token is not valid
   */
  public AccessToken verifyToken(String tokenString) throws VerificationException {
    RSATokenVerifier verifier = RSATokenVerifier.create(tokenString);
    PublicKey publicKey = retrievePublicKeyFromCertsEndpoint(verifier.getHeader());
    return verifier.realmUrl(getRealmUrl()).publicKey(publicKey).verify().getToken();
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  private PublicKey retrievePublicKeyFromCertsEndpoint(JWSHeader jwsHeader) {
    try {
      ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
      Map<String, Object> certInfos = om.readValue(new URL(getRealmCertsUrl()).openStream(), Map.class);
      List<Map<String, Object>> keys = (List<Map<String, Object>>) certInfos.get("keys");

      Map<String, Object> keyInfo = null;
      for (Map<String, Object> key : keys) {
        String kid = (String) key.get("kid");
        if (jwsHeader.getKeyId().equals(kid)) {
          keyInfo = key;
          break;
        }
      }

      if (keyInfo == null) {
        return null;
      }

      KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
      String modulusBase64 = (String) keyInfo.get("n");
      String exponentBase64 = (String) keyInfo.get("e");
      Decoder urlDecoder = Base64.getUrlDecoder();
      BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(1, urlDecoder.decode(modulusBase64));
      BigInteger publicExponent = new BigInteger(1, urlDecoder.decode(exponentBase64));

      return keyFactory.generatePublic(new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, publicExponent));

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
  }

  public String getRealmUrl() {
    return String.format("%s/realms/%s", config.getAuthServerUrl(), config.getRealm());
  }

  public String getRealmCertsUrl() {
    return getRealmUrl() + "/protocol/openid-connect/certs";
  }

}
```

4) Finally, inject the authenticator in the Websocket configuration and complete the piece of code as recommended by spring docs:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@AllArgsConstructor
public class WebSocketConfiguration extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

  @Qualifier("websocket")
  private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

  @Override
  public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
  }

  @Override
  public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/ws-paperless").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
  }

  @Override
  public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
    registration.interceptors(new ChannelInterceptorAdapter() {
      @Override
      public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
        StompHeaderAccessor accessor = MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);
        if (StompCommand.CONNECT.equals(accessor.getCommand())) {
          Optional.ofNullable(accessor.getNativeHeader("Authorization")).ifPresent(ah -> {
            String bearerToken = ah.get(0).replace("Bearer ", "");
            log.debug("Received bearer token {}", bearerToken);
            JWSAuthenticationToken token = (JWSAuthenticationToken) authenticationManager
                .authenticate(new JWSAuthenticationToken(bearerToken));
            accessor.setUser(token);
          });
        }
        return message;
      }
    });
  }

}
```

I also changed my security configuration a bit. First, I excluded the WS endpoint from spring web securty, and also let the connection methods open to anyone in the websocket security:

In WebSecurityConfiguration:

```
  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/ws-endpoint/**");
  }
```

And in the class WebSocketSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketSecurityConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

  @Override
  protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
    messages.simpTypeMatchers(CONNECT, UNSUBSCRIBE, DISCONNECT, HEARTBEAT).permitAll()
    .simpDestMatchers("/app/**", "/topic/**").authenticated().simpSubscribeDestMatchers("/topic/**").authenticated()
        .anyMessage().denyAll();
  }

  @Override
  protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

So the final result is: anybody in the local network can connect to the socket, but to actually subscribe to any channel, you have to be authenticated, so you need to send the Bearer token with the original CONNECT message or you'll get UnauthorizedException. Hope it helps others with this requeriment!

Comment: What happens if the client is still connected to your websocket endpoint and the token is not valid anymore?

Comment: @maslick it seems that the validation for the token is just executed at the time of the  connection ,when you reconnect to the websocket server, it should be generate a new token for the connection

Answer (score 8):

I was able to do websocket authentication/authorization without using Spring Security and SockJS:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class StompConfiguration implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    private final KeycloakSpringBootProperties configuration;

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/stompy");  // prefix for incoming messages in @MessageMapping
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/broker");                 // enabling broker @SendTo("/broker/blabla")
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/stomp")
                .addInterceptors(new StompHandshakeInterceptor(configuration))
                .setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }
}
```

Handshake interceptor:

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class StompHandshakeInterceptor implements HandshakeInterceptor {

    private final KeycloakSpringBootProperties configuration;

    @Override
    public boolean beforeHandshake(ServerHttpRequest req, ServerHttpResponse resp, WebSocketHandler h, Map<String, Object> atts) {
        List<String> protocols = req.getHeaders().get("Sec-WebSocket-Protocol");
        try {
            String token = protocols.get(0).split(", ")[2];
            log.debug("Token: " + token);
            AdapterTokenVerifier.verifyToken(token, KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.build(configuration));
            resp.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.SWITCHING_PROTOCOLS);
            log.debug("token valid");
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            resp.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
            return false;
        }
        catch (VerificationException e) {
            resp.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterHandshake(ServerHttpRequest rq, ServerHttpResponse rp, WebSocketHandler h, @Nullable Exception e) {}
}
```

Websocket controller:

```
@Controller
public class StompController {
    @MessageMapping("/test")
    @SendTo("/broker/lol")
    public String lol(String message) {
        System.out.println("Incoming message: " + message);
        return message;
    }
}
```

Client side (javascript):

```
function connect() {
    let protocols = ['v10.stomp', 'v11.stomp'];
    protocols.push("KEYCLOAK TOKEN");
    const url = "ws://localhost:8080/stomp";

    client = Stomp.client(url, protocols);
    client.connect(
        {},
        () => {
            console.log("Connection established");
            client.subscribe("/broker/lol", function (mes) {
                console.log("New message for /broker/lol: " + mes.body);
            });
        },
        error => { console.log("ERROR: " + error); }
    );
}

function sendMessage() {
    let message = "test message";
    if (client) client.send("/stompy/test", {}, message);
}
```

build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

    // keycloak
    implementation 'org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-boot-starter'

    // stomp.js
    implementation("org.webjars:webjars-locator-core")
    implementation("org.webjars:stomp-websocket:2.3.3")
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.keycloak.bom:keycloak-adapter-bom:$keycloakVersion"
    }
}
```

As you can see the client is authenticated during the handshake. The `HandshakeInterceptor` class extracts the token from the `Sec-WebSocket-Protocol` header. No SockJS or Spring Security is needed. Hope this helps :)

Comment: When I implement `WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer`, my IDE requires me too also implements the method `configureWebSocketTransport, configureClientInboundChannel, configureClientOutboundChannel, addArgumentResolvers, addReturnValueHandlers, configureMessageConverters`. Do you know why ?

Comment: @cactuschibre, it's very strange, since all ``WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer``  inteface's methods are default, meaning they have default implementations. Which Java version are you using?

Comment: Dear Maslick, this example is excellent and clear but could you please add the code of the KeycloakSpringBootProperties bean? How is it initialized?

Comment: Hey Andrey, I think it's part of the library, you can look here: ``org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootProperties``

Answer (score 1):

I like the answer of adrianmoya except for the part of the KeycloakTokenVerifier. I use the following instead:

```
public class KeycloakWebSocketAuthManager implements AuthenticationManager {

  private final KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver keycloakSpringBootConfigResolver;

  @Override
  public Authentication authenticate(final Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
     final JWSAuthenticationToken token = (JWSAuthenticationToken) authentication;
     final String tokenString = (String) token.getCredentials();
     try {
        final KeycloakDeployment resolve = keycloakSpringBootConfigResolver.resolve(null);
        final AccessToken accessToken = AdapterRSATokenVerifier.verifyToken(tokenString, resolve);
       ...
      }
}
```