# Securing websocket with JWT (spring +react)

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, jwt, spring-websocket

I want to secure websockets in spring boot. So far i've sucesfully managed to secure normal http requests, but having issues with websockets. I want to be able to secure and then, also, send messages to specific users. According to those sources:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-4.2.html
- [JSON Web Token (JWT) with Spring based SockJS / STOMP Web Socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30887788/json-web-token-jwt-with-spring-based-sockjs-stomp-web-socket?noredirect=1&lq=1)

i've wrote this code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 99)
@Slf4j
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserServiceDetails customUserServiceDetails;



    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/voting-socket").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
        registration.setInterceptors(new ChannelInterceptorAdapter() {
            @Override
            public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {

                StompHeaderAccessor accessor = MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);

                if (StompCommand.CONNECT.equals(accessor.getCommand())) {

                    String header = accessor.getFirstNativeHeader("Authorization");

                    log.info("Header auth token: " + header);

                    String jwt = JwtTokenProvider.getToken(header);

                    log.info("Token only : " + jwt);

                    if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(jwt)) {
                        Long userId = jwtTokenProvider.getUserIdFromJWT(jwt);

                        User user = (User) customUserServiceDetails.loadUserById(userId);

                        Principal principal = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, user.getAuthorities());

                        if (Objects.isNull(principal))
                            return null;

                        accessor.setUser(principal);
                    } else if (StompCommand.DISCONNECT.equals(accessor.getCommand())) {
                        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

                        if (Objects.nonNull(authentication))
                            log.info("Disconnected Auth : " + authentication.getName());
                        else
                            log.info("Disconnected Sess : " + accessor.getSessionId());
                    }
                }

                return message;
            }



        });
    }
}
```

and this works as expected (authentication works). However now when i want to add user registry:

```
@Autowired
private SimpUserRegistry userRegistry;
```

my code is not executed at all (but not getting any error about wiring or anything). What am i doing wrong here? Or maybe i should use some diff approach. Once again my main goals are:

- authentication
- ability to use converAndSendToUser method.

Comment: hi... were you able to solve this?